# Abrir nueva pestanaña mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Buen dia quisiera saber como abrir una nueva pestaña usando en MVC RAZOR estoy usando este codigo y funciona bien pero recarga la nueva pagina en la misma ventana y yo quiero que se conserve la pagina que ya esta, y al dar clic en el link abra una nueva pestaña de la otra vista.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Verpeliculas","Verpeliculas","Peliculas", new{id.item.PeliculaID},null)
```

Comment: Hola Senseilex. Falta informacion. Eso te funciona? No? explica qué sucede. te da errores, has hecho log?  ... etc Mira [ask] para más informacion para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta sería utilizando el último parámetro de ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Verpeliculas", "Verpeliculas", "Peliculas", new { id.item.PeliculaID }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

Estó generará un `a` con el atributo `target` y el valor `_blank` que es el necesario para que se abra en otra pestaña

```
<a href="/Peliculas/Verpeliculas/1" target="_blank">Verpeliculas</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente

```
@Html.ActionLink("String link text", "Action Name", "Controller Name", "Object Route Values", new { target = "_blank" })
```

Comment: Hola Zerx. Por favor visita el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. Has de explicar por qué tu respuesta es asi. Mira [answer] para mejorarla.Un saludo